# Smartest way of tracking Facebook-invites, Android App

Tags: android, sql, facebook, facebook-invite

So I'm planning on implementing a function to my Android app that lets you invite your friends on Facebook. When, or rather if, they choose to download the app their respective recruiter is supposed to get an in-app bonus. What would be the smartest way to implement this? I was thinking about generating some random string that they can send to their friends, and when they enter it after they've downloaded the app it adds them as 'recruits' somewhere on the recruiters database page - but it feels kinda bulky and bad.

What are your suggestions for both implementing invites and tracking them to their respective recruiter? My app works with an SQL-database so everything doesn't have to be saved only in the 'front-end' part of things.

Comment: Check out App Invites, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites It provides the ability to use “promo codes”, and then check for the code when the user opens the app.

Comment: Thank you, will give that a shot!